# Printing a form in VB.NET on Windows XP

Tags: vb.net, printing

I developed an application for a local company that required printing a chart and some data. I made the program on a Windows 7 machine using the PrintForm control. It printed just fine and I sent it to the company, but they are running it on WindowsXP and the program is crashing. I assumed that PrintForm would work on all Win operating systems but apparently that is not the case?

If there is something special that needs to be done to get PrintForm to work on XP that would be fine (downloading a lib file or something), but otherwise what is the best way to print out a VB.NET form on Windows XP?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried it on other Windows 7 PC's or just the one you're developing on?  Just because it works on your Windows 7 PC doesn't mean that it's a Windows version problem.  You should always try deploying your software on a clean Windows PC before releasing it into the wild.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is they don't have the Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.VS.dll on their PC's.  You need that to be included in your deployment project so they can call PrintForm.

I don't think this is unique to XP though.  [According to MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.printform.aspx), this has been a feature ported from the early VB days.